# How to call the future method in test class

Tags: unit-test

I am new in sfdc and i dont know how to call this method in test class. please help.

```
  @future(callout=true)
        public static void deleteRecord(Set<Id> lstId,Map<Id, 
            String> deleteRgId, String objType, String extField,String endPoint)
```

Comment: Please go through this: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_rest_callouts

Comment: i have created mock classes but i didn't understand how to call above method.

Comment: Anyone have answer?

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
Test.startTest();

yourclass.futuremethod(set,Map, 'Test1','Test2 ','Test3 ' ); - pass set , map and 3 dummy strings.

Test.stopTest();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding some more explanation of why the pattern Himanshu suggests works copied from the [Test.stopTest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm) documentation:

> All asynchronous calls made after the startTest method are collected
>   by the system. When stopTest is executed, all asynchronous processes
>   are run synchronously.

Comment: i thought its passes the arguments set , map and strings so i suggest this demo data.is something wrong?

Comment: @Himanshujasuja Yes those values can be passed. My answer is just filling in the detail that the execution all happens in Test.stopTest.